# How to parse the data frame values into postgresql statement?

Tags: r, postgresql

How to pass the data frame `d` values in to postgresql statement inside like below :

```
a<-data.frame(b=sample(letters),c=1:26)

d<-a%>%filter(c>15)%>%select(b)

e<-paste("select date,amount from table where id in ('", d,"')")
dbGetQuery(con,e)
```

**Error mesg:**

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "c("m","w"...)
LINE 1: ...type,id from table where id in ('c("m","w"...
```

getting error for the above query.Suggest me if i was wrong.

Comment: @Ronak Shah can u help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you pass to `dbGetQuery`:

```
paste("select date,amount from table where id in ('", d,"')")
 [1] "select date,amount from table where id in (' u ')" "select date,amount from table where id in (' i ')"
 [3] "select date,amount from table where id in (' s ')" "select date,amount from table where id in (' t ')"
 [5] "select date,amount from table where id in (' k ')" "select date,amount from table where id in (' l ')"
 [7] "select date,amount from table where id in (' y ')" "select date,amount from table where id in (' v ')"
 [9] "select date,amount from table where id in (' n ')" "select date,amount from table where id in (' z ')"
[11] "select date,amount from table where id in (' b ')"
```

You need to "collapse" the `d` variable to get something like ('value1', 'value2', ...):

```
sprintf("select date, amount from table where id in ('%s')", paste(d, collapse = "', '"))
[1] "select date, amount from table where id in ('u', 'i', 's', 't', 'k', 'l', 'y', 'v', 'n', 'z', 'b')"
```

Comment: how to add the numeric values instead of character type?

Comment: for the same query i want to get the numeric values in the same place of characters..but getting error due to the "c" character coming before starting the values

Comment: i am getting the error at "c" for numeric values :('c(\"3249\", \"3266\", \"3553\",")')"

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem, but if you want to pass numeric values, then you have to get rid of `'`: `sprintf("select date, amount from table where id in (%s)", paste(d, collapse = ", "))`